# Hello how can I implement the following code so that it will not make a broken image?

Tags: html

My client won an award. To display it on a website, they sent the following html:

```HTML
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.theknot.com/marketplace/redirect-2046979">
  <div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 10px; text-align: center;">
    <img src="//s3.amazonaws.com/tkpro-assets/bow_2022/section_4_3.png" 
         width="70" height="70" 
         alt="The Knot Best of Weddings - 2022 Pick" 
         border="0" 
         style="margin:0 auto; display:block;" >
  </div>
</a>
```

This is consistently coming back a broken image. Unsure of how to fix, other images on site work fine

Comment: change `//s3.amazonaws.com/tkpro-assets/bow_2022/section_4_3.png` to `https://s3.amazonaws.com/tkpro-assets/bow_2022/section_4_3.png`

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:
(note: I put the <div tag on the outside)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body class="mat-typography">
 <div style="font-size: 10px; text-align: center; width:200px; margin:0 auto">
 <a target="_blank" href="https://www.theknot.com/marketplace/redirect-2046979" style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/tkpro-assets/bow_2022/section_4_3.png" 
         width="70" height="70" 
         alt="The Knot Best of Weddings - 2022 Pick" 
         border="0" 
         style="margin:0 auto;" >
</a>
<br>
<br>
Some other text
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```